# ngb-datepicker how to get the week number of a selected date

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I want to select entire week(only working days mon-fri) once I click on a date.
I'm using Angular Material 7.3.6 and for the datepicker I'm using "NgbDatepicker" from [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#basic-usage)

First I tried to get the week number relavente to the selected date, from "getWeekNumber" as in the documentation. But it give this error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined"

I'm new to the Angular, Angular Material. My aim is to select the entire week by using week number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use moment library which is great for date functions.

Solution:

```
let weeknumber = moment(selectedDateFromPicker).week();
console.log(weeknumber);
```